# Hibernate mysql čć

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Im having problem when i try to save Patient with familyname = 'Lučić' in MYSQL database using hibernate + jpa.

When i do regular INSERT INTO, letter č and ć are displayed correctly in database and on my jsf form, so im sure that charset on my form is correct and in database.

Here is my hibernate configuration:

```
app_persistance.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
app_persistance.show_sql=true
app_persistance.generateDdl=true
app_persistance.minPoolSize=1
app_persistance.maxPoolSize=10
app_persistance.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dentapp
app_persistance.connection.username=root
app_persistance.connection.password=root
app_persistance.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app_persistance.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf8_croatian_ci
app_persistance.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
app_persistance.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
app_persistance.hbm2ddl=update
```

I tryed to debug and check if value familyname in Patient object from jsf form has right values ( č, ć ) in serviceImpl:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Patient save(Patient patient) {
    return patientDAO.save(patient);
}
```

but everything seems to be fine in patient object so it has to be some problem with hibernate configuration. When hibernate+jpa is saving patient to db, it converts č,ć to ?? characters.

Can anyone point me to something, where i should look/read/check ?

Thanks !

Comment: And how exactly did you execute INSERT INTO? Through JDBC, within the same DAO as you mention here?

Comment: I tryed to execute INSERT INTO via SQLyog.

Comment: So you didn't exercise the same JDBC connection used by Hibernate. You would prove that the problem is within Hibernate only if you established that it runs correctly over exactly the same JDBC connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your connection is not using UTF8

Change

```
app_persistance.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dentapp
```

to

```
app_persistance.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dentapp?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
```

Comment: Thanks user987339, its working now. Can you explain it little bit whats going on here ? Also i will try to google documentation for this. Thanks once again. This is the answer will accepted

Comment: characterEncoding is charset that will be used while communication with database.